# First three coefficients of $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+n}}x^n$

Tags: calculus, power-series

Given $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+n}}x^n$ find the first three coefficients of the power series $\frac{1}{f(x)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n x^n$.

I tried the following: rewrote to $(1+n)^\frac{-1}{2}$ then used binomial series. So I got $1-\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{1}{16}x^2$. Then the fraction so $1-2x-16x^2$.
But I sense this cannot be correct. Could anyone provide a helpful insight?

Comment: What does the binomial series (**?!** last time I cecked, there was that annoying caveat that the binomial series of $(1+t)^\alpha$ held for $\lvert t\rvert<1$ only...) on $(1+n)^{-1/2}$ have to do with $\frac1{f(x)}$?

Comment: To be honest it was just a wild guess. I have tried to rewrite to $a_nx^n$ but then I had $\sqrt{1+n}(-x)^n$ and could not get plain $x^n$ form.

Answer (score 2):

$$1={f(x)\over f(x)}=\left(1+{1\over\sqrt2}x+{1\over\sqrt3}x^2+\cdots\right)\left(b_0+b_1x+b_2x^2+\cdots\right)\\
=b_0+\left(b_1+{b_0\over\sqrt2} \right)x+\left(b_2+{b_1\over\sqrt2}+{b_0\over\sqrt3} \right)x^2+\cdots$$

implies $b_0=1$, $b_1+{b_0\over\sqrt2}=0$, and $b_2+{b_1\over\sqrt2}+{b_0\over\sqrt3}=0$, hence $b_1=-{1\over\sqrt2}$ and $b_2={1\over2}-{1\over\sqrt3}$, so

$${1\over f(x)}=1-{1\over\sqrt2}x+\left({1\over2}-{1\over\sqrt3} \right)x^2+\cdots$$

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method consists  in the division *by increasing powers* of $1$, up to the chosen , of the expansion of $f(x), truncated at the same order.

You should obtain, if I'm not mistaken,
$$1-\frac x{\sqrt2}+\Bigl(\frac12-\frac1{\sqrt 3}\Bigr)x^2+o(x^2).$$

Comment: I can compute these coefficients however I do not manage to get the negative sign.